# How to concatenate a list of tensors on a specific axis?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a list (my_list) of tensors all with the same shape. I want to concatenate them on the channel axis.
Helping code

```
for i in my_list:
    print(i.shape) #[1, 3, 128, 128] => [batch, channel, width, height]
```

I would like to get a new tensor i.e. new_tensor = [1, 3*len(my_list), width, height]

I don't want to use `torch.stack()` to add a new dimension. And i am unable to figure out how can I use `torch.cat()` to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a example *list* containing *10* tensors shaped `(1, 3, 128, 128)`:

```
>>> my_list = [torch.rand(1, 3, 128, 128) for _ in range(10)]
```

You are looking to concatenate your tensors on `axis=1` because the 2nd dimension is where the tensor to concatenate together. You can do so using [`torch.cat`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cat.html):

```
>>> res = torch.cat(my_list, axis=1)
>>> res.shape
torch.Size([1, 30, 128, 128])
```

This is actually equivalent to stacking your tensor in `my_list` vertically, *i.e.* by using [`torch.vstack`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.vstack.html):

```
>>> res = torch.vstack(my_list)
```